# HTTP post in jaxrs

Tags: javascript, web-services, jax-rs

I am sending some arguments from javascript to jaxrs but all i get at jaxrs is null.

Here is my code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sending(@QueryParam("var1") String var1,
@QueryParam("var2") String var2) {
System.out.println(var1+var2);
return var1 + var2;
}
```

And my Javascript:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","link",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("var1=stack&var2=flow");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `@FormParam` instead of `@QueryParam`. The difference is query parameters come in the actual URL, while form parameters are in the body. i.e.

Query Params

```
POST /rest/resource?var1=stack&var2=flow  HTTP/1.1
```

Form Params

```
POST /rest/resource  HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

var1=stack&var2=flow
```

Using `@QueryParam("var1")` gives you null because the is no query parameters in the URL with your request.